I have error when i run android app by react native: Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' not found
BUILD FAILED in 25s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Attendance_MoblieApp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 128
 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 > Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' not found.
 * Try:
 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 25s     
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
 > Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
 > Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE 5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date. 

I have get this error went to run npx react-native run-android
I want resolve this problem Can every help me resolve this

Which version did you specify for org.jetbrains.kotlin.android? Which repositories do you use? We would need to see the gradle files. You can update the question to add that information. Please make sure to properly format any code.
